# List<dynamic> is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>

Tags: wordpress, flutter, dart, httprequest, dio

i get the following exception:

```
VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' 
#0 Api.requestPosting (package:listar_flutter_pro/api/api.dart:176:31) <asynchronous suspension> 
#1 HomeCubit.onLoad (package:listar_flutter_pro/blocs/home/home_cubit.dart:18:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

My understanding is that my return send List back but my .map() function to go through each element needs a Map<String, dynamic>. How can i transform the return type to match with my existing function, because i do not want to change the existing .map function.

I appreciate every answer. Thx.

**Update:**
For better understanding my problem i have to update my initial description. This code below is working only for 1 Posts of my Wordpress rest api result. I need to extend it for all, thats the point where i need help.

Api.dart

```
  static Future<PostModel> requestPosting() async {
    final result = await httpManager.get(url: posting);
    return PostModel.fromJson(result[0]);
  }
```

As you can see result[0] pick up the first item, sure i can change it then i get another post but i need all and i am not sure if a loop to iterate through all is the elegant way to handle with wp rest api json file.

cubit.dart

```
 final response2 =
        await Api.requestPosting(); 
final posting = List.from(response.data ?? []).map((item) {
        return PostModel.fromJson(item);
      }).toList();
```

Here i need a list of PostModel instances to push it in my Widget ListTitle.

model.dart

```
 factory PostModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return PostModel(
      date: json["date"] != null ? DateTime.parse(json["date"]) : null,
      id: json['id'] ?? false,
      title: json['title']['rendered'] ?? false,
      content: json['content']['rendered'],
      data: [json]
    );
  }
```

And here i am setting up the PostingModel. I am not sure if the problem also be here to get all my Posts.

My json request is formatted like in this link, so the normal json wp rest api response: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

Answer (score 0):

You need to use generics so dart know what type are you using. For your function you can change it to:

```dart
final posting = List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(response2).map((item) {        
  print(response2);  
  return PostModel.fromJson(item); 
}).toList();
```

Api docs for generics: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generics

#### Additionally

You can `cast` it like so as well:

```dart
someList.cast<Map<String, dynamic>>().map<ReturnType>(fn);
```

Here is the api for this method:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/cast.html

Comment: That is my function: `final posting = List.from(response2).map((item) {        print(response2);  return PostModel.fromJson(item); }).toList();` i cant transfer your recommendation to it. The issue is that i got through "response2" a List<dynamic> back, but i have to go through it with my map function to create a new list.

Comment: i have updated my initial post.

Comment: Updated my response

Answer (score 0):

your created fromJson method takes a map<String, dynamic> as an argument, but you send to it dynamic comes from List.

then

1. make sure that response2 is a list of maps
2. try this PostModel.fromJson(item as Map<String, dynamic>)

   ```
    final posting = List.from(response2)
    .map((item) {
        print(response2);
        return PostModel.fromJson(item as Map<String, dynamic>);
     }).toList();
   ```

UPDATE

at Api.dart

```
 static Future<List<PostModel>> requestPosting() async {
    final List result = await httpManager.get(url: posting);
    return result.map((item) =>  PostModel.fromJson(item  as Map<String,dynamic>) ).toList();
  }
```

at cubit.dart

```
final posting = await Api.requestPosting();
```

Comment: Thx Adel for your help, but i got the same error.  `[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' #0      Api.requestPosting (package:listar_flutter_pro/api/api.dart:176:31)` I have use your code.

Comment: PostModel.fromJson(item[0] as Map<String, dynamic>);

Comment: i have updated my initial post

Comment: Still not working, it give the same error

Comment: I updated  my comment. and I wish it would help.

Answer (score 0):

here you should make a little change -:

```
 final response2 =
        await Api.requestPosting(); 
final posting = List.from(response.data ?? []).map((item) {
        return PostModel.fromJson(item as Map<String, dynamic>);
      }).toList();
```

This will work.

Comment: No sadly it doesn't work. I get the following error again: `[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
#0      Api.requestPosting (package:listar_flutter_pro/api/api.dart:175:31)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      HomeCubit.onLoad (package:listar_flutter_pro/blocs/home/home_cubit.dart:18:9)
<asynchronous suspension>`